# Viewing PDF in browser (Firefox) on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, browser, pdf

How can I view pdfs in the browser in Ubuntu?  I've found a solution to use

`apt-get install acroread mozilla-acroread acroread-plugins`

but that doesn't seem to work anymore, it says "couldn't find package".  Anyone know how to get this working?  Right now I have to download the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748) ([click here to install](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/downloads/latest/748/addon-748-latest.xpi?src=addondetail)) and [the *PDF/PPT/TIF viewer with Google docs* script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59557) ([click here to add to GreaseMonkey](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/59557.user.js)). It will load all PDFs into [Google Docs Viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on 10.10:
`sudo apt-get install mozplugger`

I think I had acroread installed (not sure, since it wasn't working), so I had to tweak mozplugger a bit to get it to work by adding a single line: `repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"`

So my file looks like:

`sudo gedit /etc/mozpluggerrc`

```
text/x-pdf:pdf:PDF file
    ACROREAD()
    [...]
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"
    [...]
    repeat noisy fill exits: evince "$file"

    application/x-dvi:dvi:DVI file [...]
```

Restarted Firefox, works great. (in FF, under edit > preferences > applications > PDF Document, it says "Use MozPlugger 1.13.3 handler")

(sorry to bring up an an old post, but this popped up on a google search for me)

Answer (score 0):

Enable extra repo sources as mentioned [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/sources). Once the extra repos have been loaded, try the command you used above, i.e, `apt-get install acroread mozilla-acroread acroread-plugins`.

If this doesn't help, add Canonical partner repo under System->Administration->Software Sources->Third Party Software.

The option should look like this:

```
URI: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu

Distrubution: jaunty

Components: partner
```

Comment: thanks, that found acroread, but not mozilla-acroread or acroread-plugins.

Comment: Try downloading and installing the files from 
http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/non-free/a/acroread/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the PDFvue add-in for Firefox?  I believe it is in experimental currently. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without installing anything, you can navigate to e.g. https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.math.harvard.edu/~seths/lecture1.pdf&embedded=TRUE where `www.math.harvard.edu/~seths/lecture1.pdf` is the URL of the PDF you're trying to view.

The `http://` after the `/viewer?url=[http://]www.` needs to be omitted in certain web browsers but not all.

The `&embedded=TRUE` at the end makes the PDF full screen size, getting rid of Google's controls and left-nav pane that shows up if you omit `&embedded=TRUE`.